# How to set up multistep form in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multi step form in React, in each step you have to enter information.

Step 1: ...some information and choose languages (you can choose multiple languages)
Step 2: ...some information
Step 3: ...some upload information
Step 4: Users answer for particular question, these question has to be shown in all languages user choose.

eg: If user has selected English and French then the user will answer the question in English and then click on save/next and then answer the question in French.

Step 5: confirm

By default the page is on step 1, user can get to next step by clicking save/next button and then step state increments and step 2 is shown, I'm not able to figure out the flow for step 4, it will be like multi step form inside multi step form which doesn't sound correct.

So if anyone knows how to do step 4 in better way, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to resolve this using single route or multiple routes?

Comment: single route will do

Comment: As you said, since you want to do multi step on step 4, you will have to break it down into sub steps. You can create a new stepper inside the step 4, that will go through each language and show the questions in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially you could have multiple steps as following

```
switch(step) {
    case 1:
        return(
            <FirstStep
                handleCaseNumber={this.handleCaseNumber}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                values={values}
            />
        )
    case 2:
        return(
            <SecondStep
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                prevStep={this.prevStep}
                handleClientVerification={this.handleClientVerification}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                values={values}
            />                
        )                
    case 3:
        return(              
            <ThirdStep
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                prevStep={this.prevStep}
                handleAccessToken={this.handleAccessToken}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                values={values}
            />
        )
    case 4:
        return(
            <FourthStep
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                values={values}
            />              
        )                                
}
```

After that in the **FourthStep** component you could have steps like that as child

```
switch(step) {
    case 1:
        return(
            <ChildStepOne
                handleCaseNumber={this.handleCaseNumber}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                values={values}
            />
        )
    case 2:
        return(
            <ChildStepTwo
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                prevStep={this.prevStep}
                handleClientVerification={this.handleClientVerification}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                values={values}
            />                
        )                               
}
```

you can follow this structure based on your need.

Comment: Yeah this could work fine, but I'm not sure as of how many language user will choose, so inside the fourth step component I can't specify the limit of steps it could be 10 or it could be just 1.

Comment: Yeah then make the steps dynamic based on language selection. To get language selection data in all the steps use contextAPI